# How to fix: "Int object not iterable" when assigning variables to two lists?

Tags: python, matrix, input

I tried making a question on this earlier and did a horrible job of explaining what I wanted. Hopefully the information I provide in this one is more helpful.

The program I am trying to make will take read input from a file in the form of the following: (there will be multiple varying test cases)

```
7 10
4 8
```

The program will assign a variable to the top-right integer (in this case, 10) and the bottom-left integer (4). The program will then compute the difference of the two variables. Here is the code I have so far -

```
with open('C:\\Users\\ayush\\Desktop\\USACO\\paint\\paint_test.in', 'r') as fn:
    matrix = fn.readlines()

input_array = []
for line in matrix:
    input_array.append(line.strip())


for p,q in enumerate(input_array):
    for x,y in enumerate(p):
        pass
    for a,b in enumerate(q):
        pass

print(y - a)
```

When I, however, run this code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ayush\Desktop\USACO\paint\paint.py", line 16, in <module>
    for x,y in enumerate(p):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
[Finished in 0.571s]
```

I'm not sure as to what the problem is, and why my lists cannot be iterated.

I hope I did a better job explaining my goal this time. Please let me know if there are any additional details I could try to provide. I would really appreciate some help - I've been stuck on this for the longest time.

Thanks!

Comment: `enumerate(p)` — `p` is index. What were you even trying to do there?

Comment: Based on the fact that it is `y-a` I suspect OP was trying to take advantage of unpacking (where the file unpacks into lines `p`, `q`, which each unpack into `(x, y)`, `(a, b)` respectively.

Comment: `for x,y in enumerate(p)` --> `for x,y in enumerate(q)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you going for something along the lines of:

```py
with open('C:\\Users\\ayush\\Desktop\\USACO\\paint\\paint_test.in', 'r') as fn:
    matrix = fn.readlines()

input_array = []
for line in matrix:
    input_array.append(line.strip())


top_line, bottom_line = input_array # previously p, q
top_right, top_left = top_line.split() # previously x, y
bottom_right, bottom_lefft = bottom_line.split() # previously a, b


print(int(top_left) - int(bottom_right)) # you would have run into issue subtracting strings without the int() calls
```

?

If so, that should work, but you can avoid all the unpacking if you just use `[0]` and `[-1]` indexes to get the first and last items (this has the advantage of working on a matrix of any size):

```py
with open('C:\\Users\\ayush\\Desktop\\USACO\\paint\\paint_test.in', 'r') as fn:
    lines = fn.read().splitlines()

matrix = [
    [
        int(item)
        for item in line.split()
    ]
    for line in lines
]

top_left = matrix[0][-1]
bottom_right = matrix[-1][0]
print(top_left - bottom_right)
```